# ruby on rails best place to put layout database code (common database calls)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, layout, model

I'm making a control panel (user accounts) in rails.
in the layout I need to show things like messages or notifications (facebook-like style).
the problem is these things require an access to database and I'm not sure where to put this code because it's not related to a controller, but the layout is shared with multiple controlers.

so where is the best place to put the code to fetch messages from database should I put in the layout itself (I don't think its right), or as helper ?

Comment: Fetching anything from the database should always happen in a controller. If your layout is shared, you might want to declare those instance variables either in several controllers (which may generate duplication) or in your ApplicationController.

Comment: Or create a separate class and have several controllers require it.

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly I should put the code in my ApplicationController or how to make a separate class ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: it very simple like  @messages = Message.all
but instead of putting it in every action of every controller there should be a better place,shouldn't it ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution was to build a control-panel controller which handles authentication and permissions and loads common user data from database such as messages...
here is an example code

```
class ControlPanelController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :get_user_data
  helper_method :mailbox
  authorize_resource

  protected
  def get_user_data
    @header_conversations=mailbox.inbox.limit(3)
    @uevents= Event.scoped
    @uevents= @uevents.after(Time.now)
  end

  def mailbox
    @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
  end

end
```

and then all the classes in my web application extends this class :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way is to use before_filter. by defining the filter in the ApplicationController (so that you can access it from any controller).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 # ..

protected

def load_messages
  @messages = Message.all 
end

end
```

and then in the any controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
before_filter :load_messages

  def index
  #  @messages is set
  end
end
```